# Rendering Local PDF in webView cuts off the right side

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, webview

I am rendering a local PDF in webView but it cuts off the right side of the PDF. Below is the code -

```
if let pdf = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("myPDF", withExtension: "pdf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil)  {
            let req = NSURLRequest(URL: pdf)

            let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0,60,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height))
            webView.scalesPageToFit = true
            webView.loadRequest(req)
            self.view.addSubview(webView)
        }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  if let pdf = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("myPDF", withExtension: "pdf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil)  {
        let req = NSURLRequest(URL: pdf)

        let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0,60,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height))

        self.view.addSubview(webView)

        webView.loadRequest(req)

    }
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Nope, its still cutting off the right side of the PDF

Answer (score 0):

I got solution -

Just moved the code from viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear, And it resolved my issue :).